# C++: Construct strait with two same typenames from template

Tags: c++, templates, struct, traits, typename

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm trying my best to construct something like this:

```
enum class Unit { km, m, cm };


template<int v, Unit u>
struct Measure {
    static const int value = v;
    static const Unit unit = u;
};


template<typename Measure, typename Measure>
struct Measures_same {
    static const bool value(const Measure m1, const Measure m2) {
        return m1.unit == m2.unit;
    }
};
```

My goal here is that I can invoke my trait like this:

```
Measures_same<Measure<1, Unit::km>,Measure<1, Unit::cm>>::value
```

, which would return false.
Obviously I am not allowed to define the same typename in the template twice (template), but I am unsure how else I should do it. If I remove one of them, the amount of arguments will not longer match.

How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do `template<typename M1, typename M2>` and use `M1` and `M2`? Also you can do this without using a static function by using `constexpr`. Additionally, it makes no sense to return a `const bool`, you might as well return `bool`.

Comment: How stupid of me, many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're doing a mix of object-oriented programming and template metaprogramming.  Probably `Measure` shouldn't be a template, as you'll probably want to change values at runtime.  Perhaps it could be a template based on the unit's dimension (length, mass, charge, etc).  If you edit your question to make a complete program (a [mcve]) so that we can see how you intend to use a `Measures_same` object, it will be clearer what needs to be changed to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Measure_same` needs to use two different template parameters. If the types are the same, the return value of `value` will always be `true`. Use:

   ```
   template<typename Measure1, typename Measure2>
   struct Measures_same { ... };
   ```
2. You don't need any inputs to `Measure_same::value`. Simply use:

   ```
   template<typename Measure1, typename Measure2>
   struct Measures_same {
       static const bool value() {
           return Measure1::unit == Measure2::unit;
       }
   };
   ```
3. Use a function call to get the `value` from `Measure_same`. Use:

   ```
   Measures_same<Measure<1, Unit::km>,Measure<1, Unit::cm>>::value()
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << Measures_same<Measure<1, Unit::km>,Measure<1, Unit::cm>>::value() << std::endl;
   ```

Comment: `value` can be a value: `static const bool value = Measure1::unit == Measure2::unit;`.

Comment: @TobySpeight, that's an option too. I stayed with the OP's idea of it being a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template specialization and some help from [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Base template (always false):

```
template<class...>
struct Measures_same : std::false_type{};
```

Specialization for two `Measures` classes with the same `Unit` argument:

```
template<int v, Unit u, int w>
struct Measures_same<Measure<v, u>, Measure<w, u>> : std::true_type{};
```

Use it like so:

```
static_assert(Measures_same<Measure<1, Unit::km>, Measure<2, Unit::km>>::value, "Fail");
static_assert(!Measures_same<Measure<1, Unit::m>, Measure<1, Unit::km>>::value, "Fail2");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8abfe36854cb653)